# Use of Tower Property

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have a Markov chain $X=\{X_0, X_1, ...\},$ with state space $S$, and a subset of states $A\subseteq S$.

Define $T_A:=\min \{n\geq 0: X_n\in A\}$.

Define notations $\,E_x[Y]:=E[Y|X_0 =x]$ for all $x\in S$ $\quad$ and $\quad$ $P_x(X_1=y):=P(X_1=y|X_0=x).$

Now for $x\notin A$, we calculate

$g(x)=E_x[T_A]=\sum_{y\in S} E_x[T_A 1_{\{X_1=y\}}]=1+ \sum_{y\in S} E_x[(T_A -1) 1_{\{X_1=y\}}].$

---

$\color{red}{\text{My teacher then wrote that}}$ $$\sum_{y\in S} E_x[(T_A -1) 1_{\{X_1=y\}}] \color{red}{=} \sum_{y\in S} P_x(X_1=y) E_x\big[ E_x[(T_A -1)|X_1=y]\big]$$ and $$E_x\big[ E_x[(T_A -1)|X_1=y]\big]\color{red}{=}E_y[T_A].$$

I guess he has applied Tower property twice to derive the two equalities above (in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$) but I don't know how he did so. The problem is that, he is conditioning on a set $[X_1=y]$ rather than on a random variable, say $X_1$. How can he applies Tower property here?

**My question:** how did he derive the two equalities above (in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$)? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your teacher has not (and could not have) applied the Tower property for the reason you mention. He has first applied the very definition of conditional probability $P(U|V)=P(U\cap V)/P(V)$ (which carries over to conditional expectation when you do it properly) to get the first red equality. To get the second he has used the Markov property.

Comment: @KurtG. Hi Kurt, thanks for the comment. I understand the second equality now (in which I guess he has also assume time homogeneity of the Markov chain). But I still have a little problem with applying your argument to get the first equality. To be more specific, I cannot prove this equality $E_x[(T_A -1) 1_{\{X_1=y\}}]=P_x\big(\{T_A-1\}\cap\{X_1=y\}\big)$, which is necessary to apply your argument. Can you comment a little bit more how can I get this equality. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sam Wong: The expectation of an indicator function is, by definition, always the probability of the subscript of the indicator function. The $T_{A} - 1$ can just be repeated because it's a function of  what $x$  currently and that is already taken care of by the second term.